# How to keep a C++ Loop running on key press but break it every lift-off

Tags: c++, loops, winapi

I have a C++ program that I'm writing for one of my games that just moves the mouse down when I press mouse1. It's an external anti-recoil function that moves the mouse down in a pattern. What I'm trying to accomplish is have a while loop constantly running, checking for the state of the key press to see if mouse1 was pressed. Once it's pressed. I have code that i want to execute UNTIL mouse1 is released. Any help would be much appreciated. The function that i have now is:

```
void ak()
{
    while ((ak) && (GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) < 0)) {
        Sleep(50);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, -4 / humanizer*modifier, 7 / humanizer*modifier, 4, 99 / waitdivider);
        Sleep(50);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, -4 / humanizer*modifier, 7 / humanizer*modifier, 4, 99 / waitdivider);
        Sleep(50);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, -4 / humanizer*modifier, 7 / humanizer*modifier, 4, 99 / waitdivider);
```

etc...

It's basically a recoil compensation. I would like for the code to go through every mouse event ONLY while mouse1 is pressed. So if I was in-game and held mouse1 down for 3 seconds. It would only execute 3 seconds worth of my code and then reset waiting for me to press it again. I hope I am being as clear as possible. I basically want to learn this logic for future projects anyways so i can do this type of loop.

Comment: This is an inefficient way to do it. If you are working on game then why not use raw input APIs?

Comment: If I get your problem correctly Why don't you use 2 whiles into each other ?

Comment: Implementing this in an event-based manner is trivial: Set up a message loop, start a timer on `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`, and kill it on `WM_LBUTTONUP`. Inject your mouse input in your `WM_TIMER`-handler.

Comment: Don't try to remove your question after you get an answer. Instead, press the green tick next to one of the answers to mark it as accepted, and your question as solved. Pick the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ((ak) && (GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) < 0)) {
```

`ak` is a pointer to function and it is guaranteed to be not equal 0, so there is no point checking that it is not equal 0.

Result of the `GetKeyState` is updated only when you regularly read message queue. In your case [GetAsyncKeyState function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx) would be better. However it would be unusable if

> The foreground thread belongs to another process and the desktop does not allow the hook or the journal record.

Nested while loop:

```
while ( true ) // TODO: better think about gracefully leaving this loop
{
    while ( GetAsyncKeyState( VK_LBUTTON ) & 0x8000 )
    {
        // TODO: your code
    }
    // TODO: sleep a little here also
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add some comments, and your precooked logic to Daniel's answer (if I correctly understand what you are expecting) is:

Edited: trimming irrelevant code, and providing newer one

```
// Returns TRUE/FALSE if that key is down currently
BOOL get_key_state(UINT key)
{
    return static_cast<BOOL>(GetAsyncKeyState(key) & 0x8000);
}

// your recoil simulating function
void simulate_recoil_on_keydown(UINT key)
{
    // keys hard coded here instead of inside the caller (i.e. WM_KEYDOWN)
    const UINT key_shoot = VK_LBUTTON;
    const UINT key_ak = VK_F1;

    if(key == key_ak)
    {
        while(TRUE)
        {
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0,0,0);

            Sleep(50);

            if(!get_key_state(key_shoot))
            {
                break;
            }

            move(-4/humanizer*modifier, 7/humanizer*modifier, 4, 99/waitdivider);

            if(!get_key_state(key_shoot))
            {
                break;
            }

            move(4/humanizer*modifier, 19/humanizer*modifier, 4, 99/waitdivider);

            if(!get_key_state(key_shoot))
            {
                break;
            }

            move(-3/humanizer*modifier, 29/humanizer*modifier, 4, 99/waitdivider);

            if(!get_key_state(key_shoot))
            {
                break;
            }

            move(-1/humanizer*modifier, 31/humanizer*modifier, 4, 99/waitdivider);

            if(!get_key_state(key_shoot))
            {
                break;
            }

            move(13/humanizer*modifier, 31/humanizer*modifier, 4, 99/waitdivider);

            if(!get_key_state(key_shoot))
            {
                break;
            }

            move(8/humanizer*modifier, 28/humanizer*modifier, 4, 99/waitdivider);

            if(!get_key_state(key_shoot))
            {
                break;
            }

            move(13/humanizer*modifier, 21/humanizer*modifier, 4, 99/waitdivider);

            if(!get_key_state(key_shoot))
            {
                break;
            }

            move(-17/humanizer*modifier, 12/humanizer*modifier, 4, 99/waitdivider);

            if(!get_key_state(key_shoot))
            {
                break;
            }

            move(-42/humanizer*modifier, -3/humanizer*modifier, 4, 99/waitdivider);

            if(!get_key_state(key_shoot))
            {
                break;
            }

            move(-21/humanizer*modifier, 2/humanizer*modifier, 4, 99/waitdivider);

            if(!get_key_state(key_shoot))
            {
                break;
            }

            move(12/humanizer*modifier, 11/humanizer*modifier, 4, 99/waitdivider);

            if(!get_key_state(key_shoot))
            {
                break;
            }

            move(-15/humanizer*modifier, 7/humanizer*modifier, 4, 99/waitdivider);

            if(!get_key_state(key_shoot))
            {
                break;
            }

            move(-26/humanizer*modifier, -8/humanizer*modifier, 4, 99/waitdivider);

            if(!get_key_state(key_shoot))
            {
                break;
            }

            move(-3/humanizer*modifier, 4/humanizer*modifier, 4, 99/waitdivider);

            if(!get_key_state(key_shoot))
            {
                break;
            }

            move(40/humanizer*modifier, 1/humanizer*modifier, 4, 99/waitdivider);

            if(!get_key_state(key_shoot))
            {
                break;
            }

            move(19/humanizer*modifier, 7/humanizer*modifier, 4, 99/waitdivider);

            if(!get_key_state(key_shoot))
            {
                break;
            }

            move(14/humanizer*modifier, 10/humanizer*modifier, 4, 99/waitdivider);

            if(!get_key_state(key_shoot))
            {
                break;
            }

            move(27/humanizer*modifier, 0/humanizer*modifier, 4, 99/waitdivider);

            if(!get_key_state(key_shoot))
            {
                break;
            }

            move(33/humanizer*modifier, -10/humanizer*modifier, 4, 99/waitdivider);

            if(!get_key_state(key_shoot))
            {
                break;
            }

            move(-21/humanizer*modifier, -2/humanizer*modifier, 4, 99/waitdivider);

            if(!get_key_state(key_shoot))
            {
                break;
            }

            move(7/humanizer*modifier, 3/humanizer*modifier, 4, 99/waitdivider);

            if(!get_key_state(key_shoot))
            {
                break;
            }

            move(-7/humanizer*modifier, 9/humanizer*modifier, 4, 99/waitdivider);

            if(!get_key_state(key_shoot))
            {
                break;
            }

            move(-8/humanizer*modifier, 4/humanizer*modifier, 4, 99/waitdivider);

            if(!get_key_state(key_shoot))
            {
                break;
            }

            move(19/humanizer*modifier, -3/humanizer*modifier, 4, 99/waitdivider);

            if(!get_key_state(key_shoot))
            {
                break;
            }

            move(5/humanizer*modifier, 6/humanizer*modifier, 4, 99/waitdivider);

            if(!get_key_state(key_shoot))
            {
                break;
            }

            move(-20/humanizer*modifier, -1/humanizer*modifier, 4, 99/waitdivider);

            if(!get_key_state(key_shoot))
            {
                break;
            }

            move(-33/humanizer*modifier, -4/humanizer*modifier, 4, 99/waitdivider);

            if(!get_key_state(key_shoot))
            {
                break;
            }

            move(-45/humanizer*modifier, -21/humanizer*modifier, 4, 99/waitdivider);

            if(!get_key_state(key_shoot))
            {
                break;
            }

            move(-14/humanizer*modifier, 1/humanizer*modifier);

            if(!get_key_state(key_shoot))
            {
                break;
            }

            Sleep(80);

            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0,0,0);

            Sleep(1000);

            // Following is not required
            //if(!get_key_state(key_shoot))
            //{
            //  break;
            //}

        }

        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0,0,0);
    }
}
```

And your WndProc should have a call something like this:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        simulate_recoil_on_keydown(wParam);
        return 0;

    // other case statements that you may already have

    }
}
```

Keeping above code simple for OP, there enough room for complete refactoring.

**In case this does not work as you expect, please share rest of the function if you have, or provide a clear pseudo-code if possible!**

Comment: @PatMiller I have updated the answer which should work. All you need to do is implement the move() function, and declare variables humanizer, modifier, waitdivider etc.

Comment: Glad you solved yourself. (mostly errors were because either you had put the functions implementation in header files, and included it multiple places, or included .cpp files) Anyway I provided the code for your original problem and I am more than sure it works as expected. About your current problem, I'm not sure what you are talking about, please elaborate.